# TypeError: util.Long.fromValue is not a function - stackdriver

Tags: node.js, stackdriver, google-cloud-logging

**PLEASE READ**: If you have a support contract with Google, please create an issue in the [support console](https://cloud.google.com/support/) instead of filing on GitHub. This will ensure a timely response.

```
    process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="path to the credentials";
    const {Logging} = require('@google-cloud/logging');

    const logging = new Logging({
      projectId: "projectId"
    });

    const logName = 'my-log';
    const log = logging.log(logName);

    const text = 'Hello, world!';
    const metadata = {resource: {type: 'global'}};

    const entry = log.entry(metadata, text);

    log
      .write(entry)
      .then(() => {
        console.log(`Logged: ${text}`);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error('ERROR:', err);
      });
```

I am getting this error

```
undefined:9
  (m.seconds=util.Long.fromValue(d.seconds)).unsigned=false
                       ^

TypeError: util.Long.fromValue is not a function
    at Type.Timestamp$fromObject [as fromObject] (eval at Codegen (/home/admin/Documents/projects/new-kroger-api/node_modules/@protobufjs/codegen/index.js:50:33), <anonymous>:9:24)
    at Type.fromObject (/home/admin/Documents/projects/new-kroger-api/node_modules/protobufjs/src/type.js:538:25)
    at Type.LogEntry$fromObject [as fromObject] (eval at Codegen (/home/admin/Documents/projects/new-kroger-api/node_modules/@protobufjs/codegen/index.js:50:33), <anonymous>:31:24)
    at Type.fromObject (/home/admin/Documents/projects/new-kroger-api/node_modules/protobufjs/src/type.js:538:25)
    at Type.WriteLogEntriesRequest$fromObject [as fromObject] (eval at Codegen (/home/admin/Documents/projects/new-kroger-api/node_modules/@protobufjs/codegen/index.js:50:33), <anonymous>:30:25)
    at Type.fromObject (/home/admin/Documents/projects/new-kroger-api/node_modules/protobufjs/src/type.js:538:25)
    at serialize (/home/admin/Documents/projects/new-kroger-api/node_modules/grpc/src/protobuf_js_6_common.js:71:23)
    at Object.final_requester.sendMessage (/home/admin/Documents/projects/new-kroger-api/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:806:37)
    at InterceptingCall._callNext (/home/admin/Documents/projects/new-kroger-api/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:419:43)
    at InterceptingCall.sendMessage (/home/admin/Documents/projects/new-kroger-api/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:464:8)
    at InterceptingCall._callNext (/home/admin/Documents/projects/new-kroger-api/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:428:12)
    at InterceptingCall.sendMessage (/home/admin/Documents/projects/new-kroger-api/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:464:8)
    at ServiceClient.Client.makeUnaryRequest (/home/admin/Documents/projects/new-kroger-api/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:536:21)
    at ServiceClient.method_func (/home/admin/Documents/projects/new-kroger-api/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:950:43)
    at /home/admin/Documents/projects/new-kroger-api/node_modules/@google-cloud/logging/build/src/v2/logging_service_v2_client.js:188:39
    at Task.timeoutFunc [as _apiCall] (/home/admin/Documents/projects/new-kroger-api/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/api_callable.js:143:16)
    at Task.run (/home/admin/Documents/projects/new-kroger-api/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/bundling.js:195:18)
    at BundleExecutor._runNow (/home/admin/Documents/projects/new-kroger-api/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/bundling.js:421:14)
    at Timeout._timers.(anonymous function).setTimeout [as _onTimeout] (/home/admin/Documents/projects/new-kroger-api/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/bundling.js:367:22)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
    at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5
```

this error is occurring at position log.write I don't know why it is throwing this error please help me

Answer (score 4):

This same error was happening to me using google firebase node api in a lambda function.
This was happening due to a module globally overwriting the `Long` type of protobuf.js. It is most likely and old version of the `long` module. Even if you do not have this module in your package.json, it could be being loaded as a dependency of another module.

In my case, some dependency was using `long 1.1.2`. And `protobuf.js` needed `long 4.0.0`. Newer node & npm versions should automatically solve this collisions when doing `npm install`

However, I solved it by upgrading `long` directly inside the `node_modules` folder. Or you can also do it inside `package_lock.json` file.

The following issue explain this in detail: https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore/issues/336

Comment: I was facing this issue while creating grpc client in node js and installing long 4.0.0 in package.json solved my issue, thanks man you saved my hours because i had no clue why that was happening.