# Can't set number on Firestore document

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to set a document on Firestore with a number field.
I just followed [an example from the official document of Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#data_types).

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
admin.initializeApp({
  /* I set here properly */
});

const db = admin.firestore();

function setPost() {
  const docRef = db.collection('posts').doc();
  await docRef.set({
    postId: v4(), // uuid
    createdAt: Date.now(), // it is a number. and it occurs an error.
  });
};
```

**Error**

> Failure: 13 INTERNAL: Request message serialization failure: util.Long.fromValue is not a function
> Error: 13 INTERNAL: Request message serialization failure: util.Long.fromValue is not a function

If I wrapped `Date.now()` with `${}`, it works well.

```
await docRef.set({
  postId: v4(), // uuid
  createdAt: `${Date.now()}`, 
});
```

**Update**

I also tried with the below code but it still throws the same error.

```
await docRef.set({
  postId: v4(), // uuid
  createdAt: 123, 
});
```

Comment: Could you point to where you found this specific example?

Comment: @AlexL I add a link to an example.

Comment: Hey, the link that you mention doesn't use `Date.now()` but rather `new Date()`, and more specifically in the node.js calls it specifies a `Timestamp.fromDate` function that it uses to convert the Date value into a Timestamp that Firestore will accept with ease. (What's more, the error message you're getting seems to be similar to [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54146716/typeerror-util-long-fromvalue-is-not-a-function-stackdriver) , where some other library is overwriting the `Long` from `util`). So if not node.js, what examples are you following from the docs?

Comment: @fabc thank you for your answer, but I changed `Date.now()` to simple numbers like `1`, `123` but it still doesn't work with same error.

Comment: You didn't read the link @fabc provided.  The problem in in Node, and specifically related to number arguments (i.e. `long`).  your one method to avoid the error converted the value to a STRING, i.e. object literal ``` `$${Date.now()}` ``` which would obviously avoid the need for protobuf to call on util.long.  Upgrade the node package.json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the error in the "Long" itself in your project. On other questions appeared to be the version of the long package is old and you have to update it, even if manually (take a look at the long package, if there was one, in the node_modules),may be another package used an old one. If you don't see them before take a look at this questions :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57499044/13058371
https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/issues/1472

Comment: You're right. I did `npm audit` and it was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in https://stackoverflow.com/a/57499044/2434784 the issue is a package conflict in Node, specifically related to number arguments (i.e. `long`).  Your one method to avoid the error converted the value to a STRING, i.e. object literal `` `${Date.now()}` `` which would obviously avoid the need for protobuf to call on util.long.  Upgrade the node package.json.